# how to protect AlarmManager from task manager

Tags: android, memory-management, task, alarmmanager, taskmanager

I have implemented simple application which triggers alarm on given time. Every thing works fine.

```
Myalarm m = new Myalarm(this);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + alarmtimeinmilliseconds, pendingIntent);
```

BUT when i setup an alarm and if i run task manager and press "close all tasks" or "clear memory". it also kills my alarm which i have set.

How to protect my alarm with killer, brutal task manager :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't, most likely.

Android does not have a task manager that has "close all tasks" or "clear memory". Presumably, you are thinking of some task manager that comes with your device. If they elected to unschedule your alarms, there is nothing much you can do about it. In standard Android, if the user goes into Settings and clicks "Force Stop" on your app, that too will unschedule your alarms, and there is nothing that you can do about it.

What you *can* do is log when your alarms occur, such as in a `SharedPreference`. Then, when the user launches your activity, you can check your log. If it has been far too long since the last recorded event, you can assume that the user did something to unschedule your alarms, and you can reschedule them.